# PHP 7 How to find if PHP was built with LDAP support?

Tags: php, ldap, php-7.2

Using Linux, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2

I am updating a production PHP site that has a horribly insecure LDAP authentication process. However, trying to call ldap_connect() gives me an undefined function error. So, as I see it there are two possibilities:

1. PHP was not built with LDAP support (using --with-ldap[=DIR])
2. PHP was built with LDAP support but the extension is not installed

So, how do I tell which is the case?

For extra fun, phpinfo() does not have an ldap section. However, `extension_loaded('ldap');` returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and check it with [extension_loaded()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) like this:

```
$builtWithLdap = extension_loaded('ldap');
```

or alternativly as a crowbar approach, just check if one of the [functions exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php):

```
$builtWithLdap = function_exists('ldap_add');
```

**Edit:** Re-reading your question I just realize you actually want to know if you can distinguish whether it was built with support but not loaded or built without support. As far as I am aware in the runtime those are the very same things as PHP just wont know anything about it. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

*"undefined function error"* pretty clearly says that you don't have LDAP support. It either hasn't been built in statically, or has been built dynamically but hasn't been loaded. In the phpinfo output, it should show what ini file was parsed. Edit that file and look for the `extension_dir` directive. This will list the directory where the dyanmic extensions are installed. List the files in that directory. If there is no `ldap.so` file, then you don't have LDAP built at all, and you'll need to install/build it yourself. If there is such a file, then you just need to load it by adding (or uncommenting) `extension = ldap.so` in the ini file and then restarting Apache.

[**Update**] Based on your edit, the two statements "ldap_connect() gives me an undefined function" and "extension_loaded('ldap'); returns true" seem contradictory. Please post the actual code and the actual error message.